# Need slider label in Manipulate expression to show more digits

Tags: manipulate

How can I get the display for the manipulator to have more digits. It currently expresses 5 digits but I need 10.

Comment: Do you have a code example we can start with?

Comment: I don't have it with me now, as I am on my phone(not near the computer). It's a traditional plot using manipulate, I just need the display for the slider to have more digits. I've tried SetPrecision but it says manipulate has too many arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Manipulate[Plot[Sin[x (1 + a x)], {x, 0, 6}], 
 {a, 0, 2, Labeled[Manipulator[##], SetPrecision[a, 10], Right] &}]
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can use `NumberForm` instead of `SetPrecisions`, say, `Labeled[Manipulator[##], NumberForm[a, {20, 15}], Right] &`.